# Printing multiple-images as a single pdf using powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing

My code below:

```
$Source = "C:\Users\xxxx"
$targetFolder = "C:\Users\xxx\new"

 Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include * | forEach-Object{
 $fileObject = $_
$filename = $_.BaseName.Substring(26)
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Include * | forEach-Object{
$tempObject = $_
$temp = $_.BaseName.Substring(26)

if($temp -eq $filename -And $tempObject -ne $fileObject){

Start-Process $fileObject + $tempObject  -Verb Print -ArgumentList $targetFolder

}
}
```

I'm able to successfully match files based on part of their names, now I'd like to print the two matching images vertically on top of each other as a PDF, the Printer name would be "Microsoft Print to PDF"

What I truly want is as long as the images are matching according to my if statement, to be combined into one image, if there's another solution that can make that happen I'm open to it as well!!!

Any ideas????

Comment: I'm pretty sure powershell doesen't have a native command to create a pdf file. Google for a 3rd party commandline tool which can do that

Comment: @guiwhatsthat As long as I name the Printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" it works fine, I just have to click Print everytime, but I can't get 2 images in one PDF thats all.

Comment: can't create rtf with images...